# Google Search by Image API?

Tags: google-image-search

for my job, I'm looking into an idea in which people would use Google Search by Image and use any celebrity photo they find.  Google would return the results and then on our end, a there'd be a database of professionals showing how to get that specific look.

I'm assuming this is extremely unlikely to do, based on that users could use ANY photo.

So, is there a way that I could have about 100 or so celebrity photos that Google Image results could compare to and then choose the one that is closest.

Basically:

1. Drag drop photo of Britney Spears
2. Google searches with that image
3. Google's results compare the top images with our 100, and selects the closest match.
4. User gets to see video of how to get Britney Spears look.

I'm not a programmer, but looking for some API or Search by Image extension that could make this remotely possible for the programmers here at my job.  Does something like that (a search by image api) exist?  The best I could find was just the support page, which is hardly of any help: http://support.google.com/images/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=searchbyimagepage&answer=1325808

Comment: i wrote code using python to download  full resolution images from google search  follow this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28487500/2875380 but you have to enter a query and the script will  download 100 images for that query

Comment: @rishabhr0y Your code does not seem to meet the requirement of being able to upload a picture to search with...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sorry to say, but the Google image API is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/image-search/):

> Important: The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited.

Quite sure there are some alternatives (http://www.tineye.com/ and http://mrisa.mage.me.uk)

Update (2013): There is now [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) which allows image searches.

Comment: Ah, bummer.  Didn't see that, thanks for the link.  I'll take a look at Tineye

Comment: Maybe I'm skimming over it too much, but as far as I understand it the Google Image Search API is for finding images based on text. Does (or did) it also do reverse image searching?

Comment: Updated one won't works for search with uploaded image. Only works for finding images based on text.

Comment: But, isn't Custom-Search limited to only defined Sites ? So... not entire internet-catalog but only few defined sites ? For me it's no go...

Comment: I am also looking to know if you can search images Google wide with the new API, is it possible ?

Comment: @xavier i wrote code using python to download  full resolution images from google  follow this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28487500/2875380

Comment: Is it possible to get programatic results of result images by searching for image through its url?

Answer (score 53):

You can easily search by an existing image by inserting this into your address bar:

https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&sa=X&image_url=**YOUR_IMAGE_URL**

Example:

https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&sa=X&image_url=http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png

Comment: Hi. Did you were able to scrap the response ? and to get a title ?

Comment: what about using local image file?

Comment: Here is another link where you can actually add a link or upload your own image: https://www.google.com/imghp?sbi=1

Comment: this doesn't work if the URL isn't publically accessible

Comment: Is it possible to get programatic results by searching for an image with its img_url? I need to perform this in a nodejs environment.

Comment: Google Custom Search, maybe? https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Answer (score 5):

These answers are quite obsolete, but the question comes up in searches. So, the [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) has the "web detection" feature that does a reverse image search. First 1000 requests per month are free, $3.50/1000 afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I think [Google Web Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/internet-detection) could be a solution for you. Google moved it permanently from Image search

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via www.images.google.com but only from a browser (lets you upload your own image and compares it to similar).
I'm working on doing it from code (not from browser).

Comment: then you could do it programmatically with the selenium WebDriver

Comment: I'd be interested to see if Google has done anything to prevent that... Did you complete your code? Did it work?

Comment: I built something in Selenium to test this, they blocked me after ~1000 requests. Would have loved to pay them to make requests officially through an API, there's clearly demand for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came up with two solutions:

1. There are a number of APIs that give reverse image search results nowadays. The ones I used are https://reverseimageapi.com and TinEye.com.
2. As the selected answer mentions, you can easily scrape this information but will almost certainly need rotating proxies to prevent being banned by the search engine. There are plenty of proxy rotation services (Zyte, Oxylabs, ScrapingBee, etc.) to make you life easier.

I ended up going with option 1 due to the upkeep of scraping search engines and elements changing / breaking.