# automatically upload an image to google "search by image" using C#

Tags: c#, image, search

I want to see how to automatically upload an image to google "search by image" using C# code. Assume that I have a photo "C:\photo.jpg" and I want to upload to google search by image to get the result page.

Comment: Put it on a web site and Google will find it.

Answer (score 0):

As Google have not released an API for "Search by Image" It is not possible to programatically   search by an image.

[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api)

Comment: oh I think it is possible. It uses an Href behind the camera icon in the image.google.com. the href uses an javascirp code to do so but I dont know how.

Comment: your still only going to get back a website of images, versus say with an API you could get an xml file with the URI of each image.