# Using Google for Image Search from a Mobile app

Tags: c#, android, api, windows-phone-7

I'd like to implement the following: in a mobile app (Android, Windows Phone) the user takes a photo, and my app searches for such an image on the web. I was told that Google has something like that. I found [a page about Google Image Search](https://developers.google.com/image-search/), but it is written that it is deprecated. It advises to use Custom Search instead, but I didn't find image search there (only text search).
My question is: does a solution for image searching from a mobile app exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google provide api for image search through keyword, you are looking for search through image ? may be this can of any help [Google Search by Image API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api)

if you are looking for search by image [tineye api](http://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI) is useful

Comment: Yes, in that answer the same link to deprecated google image search is provided...

Comment: google api is deprecated so you can use tineye if you want to achieve image search