# Programmatically Search For Image

Tags: javascript, image, api, search

So I built this fun little website for my friends and myself -- quotegen.meteor.com -- and I thought it would be cool to have it search the web (via. Google, Bing, etc) for an image corresponding to the quote and display it in the background. However, I can't find an api that will do this for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

What I want to do is call an api that searches for an image, then presumably returns an object with URL's and other information, and then insert the image of the first result.

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api

Comment: It highly depends on what you want.
If you want the first item that you search to be displayed then it could be done.
Although your question is very vague and I am only assuming as to what you want.

Comment: That answer unfortunately is out of date user1477388

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is google custom search which allows for image search

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview This will allow you to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Would this work for finding the headline image of an article on a news outlet like bbc or nbc? I'm practicing and making an RSS reader but find many feeds are missing images.