# Searching in google using image

Tags: java, android, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I have an android app that should search in google using image.. User should upload photo and search using it..

I have that code to choose photo to search..

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
    "Select Picture"), GALLERY_CODE);
```

I searched in google, and I found only that..

[ImageSearch](https://github.com/tonytamsf/Android-Image-Search)

But that searches for images using keyword.. I don't want that..

Also I tried to search in Bing using image but I couldn't.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Google Custom Search JSON/Atom API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)

> The JSON/Atom Custom Search API lets you develop websites and applications to retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search programmatically. With this API, you can use RESTful requests to get either web search or image search results in JSON or Atom format.

You can find an alternative way here: [Google Search by Image API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api) using [TinEye API](http://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I tried to search for Google Custom Search example for android but can't find one..