# Google Reverse Image Search via API?

Tags: android, rest, post, google-api, google-custom-search

Is it possible to perform a reverse image search via the Google Custom Search API using `https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=<URL>` or `https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&sa=X&image_url={YOUR_IMAGE_URL}`, as I think sending direct requests to the servers and scraping the results is against the TOS. This method was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api), but I am unsure if this can be done through the API or not, to avoid violating the TOS if possible.

This example `GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures` was given by Google in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest#making_a_request), so I was thinking if there was possibly a way to POST the previous URL's in a similar fashion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I've noticed on the official Google Custom Search forum, that is the most requested feature, but that is not possible - at the moment. And I don't know if / when it will be.