# Image finding search on website

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I'm Working on a project were users upload image in website and get the image details. But i'm not getting a way out i have tried google search in my project but in does not take image as input.

Please suggest me the way how can i integrate image finding search in my website

### THANKS IS ADVANCE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Search by Image API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api)

Answer (score 0):

There is an API by Google https://cloud.google.com/vision/ to get meta data and image details, you may use it to customize and fulfill your requirement.